# Doctrine get 10 most recent records sorted from oldest to newest

Tags: sorting, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm stuck with a simple request that seems not so easy to perform.
I want to get the last 10 records of a table, so I was doing this:

```
$records = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('Bundle:Rec')
    ->findBy(array(), array('created' => 'DESC'), 10)
;
```

The problem is that the records will be sorted in descending order.
What is the most efficient way to get those same record but in ascending order?

Comment: Can't you simply use `array('created' => 'ASC')`?

Comment: He try to sort the DESC result so `array('created' => 'ASC')`Not working

Comment: My bad, didn't properly understand the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort your records with [uasort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uasort.php):

```
$records = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('Bundle:Rec')
    ->findBy(array(), array('created' => 'DESC'), 10)
;

uasort($records, function ($first, $second) {
    return $first->getCreated() > $second->getCreated() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: I just tried and I get this error 
Error: Call to a member function matching() on array

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong but $records being an array, it doesn't have a getIterator() method

Comment: @JulienM You were right, my bad. I've edited my answer with what I think is the most efficient way (no need to create an ArrayCollection), could you look at it?

Answer (score 0):

@Veve I have changed your (deleted) answer to this:

```
$records = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('Bundle:Rec')
        ->findBy(array(), array('created' => 'DESC'), 10)
;

$recCollection = new ArrayCollection($records);
$iterator = $recCollection->getIterator();
$iterator->uasort(function ($first, $second) {
    return $first->getCreated() > $second->getCreated() ? 1 : -1;
});

$measurements = $iterator;
```